# Ansible omit on given value

Tags: ansible

I have a set of data objects I'm passing to a template, and when I render the template I want to omit a given line if the value in the array is `null`.

Example array:

```
[
  { 
    'name': 'one'
    'place': 'high'
    'value': 'set'
  }
  {
    'name': 'two'
    'place': null
    'value': 'unset'
  }
  {
    'name': 'three'
    'place': 'low'
    'value': 'whyme'
  }
]
```

Sample template:

```
{% for item in array %}
  - name: {{ item.name }}
    place: {{ item.place | default (omit) }}
{% endfor %}
```

The `default(omit)` filter isn't working the way I want it to. It's putting the "place:" line into the output with no value. I want the "place:" line to not appear in the output at all.

Actual output:

```
- name: one
  place: high
- name: two
  place:
- name: three:
  place: low
```

Desired output:

```
- name: one
  place: high
- name: two
- name: three
  place: low
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template below does the job

```
{% for item in array %}
  - name: {{ item.name }}
{% if item.place %}    place: {{ item.place }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

gives

```
  - name: one
    place: high
  - name: two
  - name: three
    place: low
```

with the data properly structured

```
array: [
  { 
      'name': 'one',
      'place': 'high',
      'value': 'set',
  },
  {
      'name': 'two',
      'place': null,
      'value': 'unset',
  },
  {
      'name': 'three',
      'place': 'low',
      'value': 'whyme',
  }
]
```